# Is there a way to get all the power-ups in the red mushroom houses in New Super Mario Bros. Wii?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

Are there any patterns to the power-up panels in the red mushroom houses in New Super Mario Bros. Wii?  Is there a way I can tell where the Bowser/Bowser Jr. panels will be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each level has 6 different layouts. Once I had those in text form I wrote a small program that generated a PDF based on these. The items with green background do not have any Bowser (Jr) in that world in that position and can be safely clicked (if you know the green patterns, you always get **at least** 3 items from the red mushroom).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Each world has 6 possible panel combinations. There is a [guide on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs/58295) detailing the different panel combinations, and which ones you should hit to test what the current arrangement is.

Also, here's a [visual guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs/58356) to the panels.

Comment: Awesome!  I found someone who converted those tables to images which makes it easier: http://members.cox.net/crashnbur/mario/ .

Comment: That's a really nice resource; I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: The link to the visual guide gives a 404 error, here's one on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs/58356)

Comment: @Fambida Thanks for catching that. I'll edit this new link in.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late ;-) but I wrote a little tool to help you find the correct panel. You can find it here: https://wischi-chr.github.io/MarioWiiPowerUps/

And the source is on github: https://github.com/wischi-chr/MarioWiiPowerUps